# JSON is losing double quotes when saving in MySql in Python. How to solve it?

Tags: mysql, json, python-3.x

I have the following code in Python 3.7 that works properly - should save the JSON object inside a MySql database:

```
jsonSerialized = json.dumps('{"k":"some data","l":"some data2"}')
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('+jsonSerialized+')') #It works
```

Result is `{"k":"some data","l":"some data2"}`.

But the following code is saving the JSON in the database without the double quotes:

```
jsonObject = {"k":"some data","l":"some data2"}
jsonSerialized = json.dumps('%s'%jsonObject)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES ('+jsonSerialized+')') #It doesn't work
```

The result is `{'k': 'some data', 'l': 'some data2'}` which is losing the double quotes and losing the JSON formatting.

I'm going to receive the jsonObject from another process and I would like to have it well formatted in the database.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: The string is already JSON, why are you calling `json.dumps()` on it.

Comment: `cursor.execute("INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (%s)", (jsonObject,))`?

Comment: @Barmar if I do `jsonSerialized = '%s'%jsonObject` (removing `json.dumps()`) I get an error `Error: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''k': 'some data', 'l': 'some data2
'})' at line 1`

Comment: I meant why aren't you using `jsonSerialized = '{"k":"some data","l":"some data2"}'` since that string is already in JSON format.

Comment: Using `jsonSerialized = '{"k":"some data","l":"some data2"}'` gives me `ProgrammingError: 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '"k":"some data","l":"some data2"})
' at line 1`

Comment: @Nick your syntaxe gives me an error (jsonObject,) is missing something. `cursor.execute('INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (%s)', jsonObject)` gives me `1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '%s)' at line 1`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need to encode as JSON twice, you just need to use the correct `cursor.execute()` syntax for substituting a parameter.

```
jsonSerialized = json.dumps(jsonObject)
cursor.execute('INSERT INTO messages (message) VALUES (%s)', (jsonSerialized,))
```

Comment: could you explain this portion `, (jsonSerialized,)` ? The second paramether of  `cursor.execute()`

Comment: It's a tuple containing the value of `jsonSerialized`. `cursor.execute()` replaces each `%s` in the SQL with the corresponding element of the tuple argument.